# Finding an average in Excel on continuous data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible to use the `AVERAGE` function on data that is recorded automatically and repeatedly, but starts over after an undefined time period?

- **Column 1** is the number of the sample on a given machine. So it will be 1, 2, 3, etc.
- **Column 2** is the actual data recorded from the test device. It will be 4.35, 3.46, 7.89, etc.
- **Column 3** says `DAQ Start` on the row where sample one is recorded.  Then when that sampling series is done it will say `DAQ PAUSE`.

There may be 15 or 20 samples taken in each test. Then when the next sampling begins, it will start over with `DAQ Start`, and continue until that sampling is done. This repeats many times on one spreadsheet.

Is there a way to have the spreadsheet do an average for each sampling? I cannot use the actual data, as there is no defined set of samples, so the cell reference changes with each one.

I would like to use the `DAQ Start` and `DAQ Pause` cells to set the reference for each average. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

You could probably do some magic with `AVERAGEIF`, `MATCH`, and `OFFSET`.

I would just sort the data, add a column that increments at each "DAQ Start" row to identify the sample series, and then use a PivotTable to find the average per sample series.

To spell it out, add column D and use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(C2="DAQ Start",D1+1,D1),1)
```

The `IFERROR` is just to make it clean. This column increments each time it hits "DAQ Start".

[image: Fourth column for "Series"]

Then select the whole set of data and columns and create a PivotTable (on the Insert ribbon). Set the "Series" as the rows and average of "Data" as the values. You now have the average of each series.

[image: PivotTable using "Series" as rows and "Data" as values]

Comment: My reading of the question is that there will be other irrelevant data before the first start, between each pause and the next start, and after the last pause. Data are sampled continuously, and start and pause indicate when the user actually cares about it. You'll either have to manually delete the irrelevant data to clean up, or have the irrelevant data belong to another series (e.g. series 0).

Comment: It would be nice to get some feedback on the answers from @927m or a sample spreadsheet. I think I might just go negative if there are in-between readings. `=IFERROR(IF(C2="DAQ Start",1+(0-D1),IF(C2="DAQ Pause",0-D1,D1)),0)`

Answer (score 0):

I don’t really understand what you have in <del>Column 1</del> Column `A`,
but it seems to be unimportant, so I’ll ignore it. 
If it’s important, please explain it better.

I’ll assume that your data start in Row 1;
i.e., you have no header row.  Put

```
=IF(C1="DAQ Start", AVERAGE(OFFSET(B1, 0, 0, MATCH("DAQ PAUSE",C1:C$8,0), 1)), "")
```

into cell `D1` (or wherever you want the average to go). 
Change the 8 (in `C$8`) to the number of the last row where you have data —
or a larger number (e.g., 999)
if (as you say) data are added frequently/automatically,
and the rows between the good data and Row 999 are blank. 
Then drag/fill cell `D1` down as far as you need to cover all your data.

- `=IF(C1="DAQ Start", …, "")` says to just display blank in Column `D`
  on any row where Column `C` is not `DAQ Start`.

  On rows where Column `C` *is* `DAQ Start` (the first row of a test),
- use `MATCH("DAQ PAUSE",C1:C$8,0)` to find the first occurrence
  of `DAQ PAUSE` in Column `C` below the current row. 
  This returns the relative position of that value. 
  For example, if it were in the current row, `MATCH` would return 1 —
  but, of course, that is impossible,
  because the current row contains `DAQ Start` there. 
  But if the `DAQ PAUSE` were on the next row, `MATCH` would return 2.
- `OFFSET(B1, 0, 0, MATCH("DAQ PAUSE",C1:C$8,0), 1)`
  specifies the range starting at the cell in Column `B` on the current row
  (with offsets of 0 and 0)
  that’s tall enough to reach down to the `DAQ PAUSE` row
  (using the return value from `MATCH` as the number of rows)
  and one (1) column wide.
- `AVERAGE(OFFSET(B1, 0, 0, MATCH("DAQ PAUSE",C1:C$8,0), 1))` computes the average of that range.

For example,

[image: example sheet]

the average of 2, 3, and 10 is 5, and the average of 1, 2, 3, and 42 is 12. 
I wasn’t clear
what might be between the end of one test and the beginning of another;
as long as it’s not `DAQ Start`, my function doesn’t care.